# How to scroll up in PowerShell inside "screen" command?

Tags: command-line, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling, buffer

I'm using Windows 11 Powershell and inside a `screen -d -r` command that doesn't let me scroll by default. The text inside the `screen` is too much to fit inside my actual screen! So I'm looking for a way to scroll up. In Linux, I know a way to do that but in PowerShell, I'm struggling.

So far none of these worked, help please:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> (When I do this it says "copy mode aborted")
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (This will open windows search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it! First do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, this will enable "copy mode". It will write a small notification to verify copy mode is enabled. Then use <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

To exit use <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

To enter scroll mode, use the following keys in sequence :
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>.
Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to terminate the scroll mode.

You may also use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>
to scroll by line when in normal mode.